# Whats the significance of -H, -d etc in a curl command

Tags: curl

I am trying to run a curl command in my terminal in mac os, and have to implement the following code as per the documentation I see. Whats the significance of -H and -d here:

```sh
curl https://api.abcd.com/orders/regular \
    -H "X-Kite-Version: 3" \
    -H "Authorization: token api_key:access_token" \
    -d "tradingsymbol=ACC" \
    -d "exchange=NSE" \
    -d "transaction_type=BUY" \
    -d "order_type=MARKET" \
    -d "quantity=1" \
    -d "product=MIS" \
    -d "validity=DAY"
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can find more info by running in terminal: `man curl` and basically

`-H` - specifies HTTP request header, in your case: `X-Kite-Version & Authorization`,

`-d` - specifies HTTP request body data, in your case parameters: `tradingsymbol, exchange, ...`

Why do you need this all: because that's the way in which http protocol works .

Answer (score 0):

Basically, you are trying simulate a form and send it to url.

The form contains Header token and input data.

-H for Header token

-d for data or input tag in html